# SELECT from table where col1 AND col1

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run this MySQL Query:

```
SELECT SUM(arg2) as talktime FROM voipnow.ast_queue_log 
        WHERE queuename = '0536*401' 
        AND DATE(time) = '2014-03-17' 
        AND (event = 'COMPLETECALLER' AND event = 'COMPLETEAGENT') 
        ORDER BY time DESC
```

but no results are being returned, I have also tried:

```
SELECT SUM(arg2) as talktime FROM voipnow.ast_queue_log 
        WHERE queuename = '0536*401' 
        AND DATE(time) = '2014-03-17' 
        AND event = 'COMPLETECALLER' AND event = 'COMPLETEAGENT')
        ORDER BY time DESC
```

but still no results

Comment: You should provide sample of your data, and explain what you are trying to achieve. Queries that you pasted are ok technically, there is probabl an error in logic and for that to be resolved one needs to see your data and understand your intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder how a column could have two different strings in the same time, maybe you meant to use `OR` instead of `AND` To have all the records which have either `COMPLETECALLER` and `COMPLETEAGENT`

```
SELECT SUM(arg2) as talktime FROM voipnow.ast_queue_log 
    WHERE queuename = '0536*401' 
    AND DATE(time) = '2014-03-17' 
    AND (event = 'COMPLETECALLER' OR event = 'COMPLETEAGENT')
    ORDER BY time DESC
```